# HTTPClient Requesting JSON with login Credentials C# Sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I need to make an http request for JSON data on a sharepoint site.  When accessing the data through the browser, I am first prompted for a username and password.   After entering my credentials I am allowed to see the JSON.  I am new to C# and am wondering the best way go about forming my request, retrieving the response, and parsing the JSON.  I have worked with JSON requests in java before, but never had to deal with sharepoint credentials.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = uname.Text;
    string password = pword.Text;
    string url = "THE SITE URL HERE";
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    var response = req.GetResponse();
    //Do Stuff with response
}
```

Comment: XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

Comment: This looks great, but for some reason when I try to load the response stream into an XMLDocument I get "Data at the root level is invalid...".  Any ideas why?    If I output the responseStream to the console I get "System.Net.ConnectStream"

Comment: Stream is not a string... you need to read it first.
            `using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a WebRequest and either pass in your credentials there or if that doesn't work check out this answer about setting your sharepoint credentials.

You should just be fine making an HttpWebRequest and setting the ClientCertificates property to include your certificate from it's .pfx file, unless you've got some other permissions issue going on, because you don't need to have a ServerCertificateValidationCallback handler in order to establish an SSL connection to a remote server as a client. The handler's only necessary if you wish to intercept, inspect, and/or override the default validation behavior of the remote machine's certificate.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595049/servicepointmanager-servercertificatevalidationcallback-question